# Lack of PredictRecommendation/3 method

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I'm working on recommendation system, which uses ML.Net and currently I've been having problems with predicting single value while creating a model. It wasn't happening before (while using the same dataset). The other problem may be negative RSquared Value of the Matrix Factorization, but I'm not sure.

I have also tried to fix Visual Studio but it did nothing.

Here are the logs:

> (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Info) 2021-06-02
> 12:13:26.5086 DEBUG Cannot find method „PredictRecommendationAsync/3”
> in class Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLEngine. Causes:     w
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    w
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    w
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
> w StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__94`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    w Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.AutoMLServiceFactory.AutoMLServiceProxy.<PredictRecommendationAsync>d__19.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    w Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.TrainSession.<PredictRecommendationAsync>d__53.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> w
> Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.EvaluateTabControl.<TryItOutText_Click>d__5.MoveNext()
> (Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.Utils.Logger.Debug)

Comment: Looks like this is from Model Builder. I would add an issue about this on their GitHub page - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling of the Model Builder has worked out.